# pass a method with parameters as string and when assigning to variable as a method(not as a string) in R

Tags: r

I have a to use a paste0 method with different arguments based on condition. Please refer the below code for understanding.

```
df:
fruit    country      tons
mango    usa          100      
mango    ind          120
apple    usa          50  
mango    spain        60
apple    ind          70       
apple    china        90
mango    canada       150

if(fruit == "apple") {
appdf <- df %>% group_by(fruit) %>% summarise(final_result = paste0(tons, "(", "month)",collapse=",")))

} else if(fruit == "mango"){
mangodf <- df %>% group_by(fruit) %>% summarise(final_result = paste0(tons, collapse = ",")))
}
```

Like above I have redundant code in both if and else block except what ever there in the paste0 method. I want to replace this paste0 logic dynamically and want to keep one block of code for both apple and mango. (above is logic is for reference only, in real case each block paste0 method has different column names which not available in other block data frame)

I tried using quo but no luck(not sure "quo" will help in this case)

```
fruit_info <- if(fruit=="apple") {
        c(applemonth = quo(paste0(tons, "(", "month)",collapse=",")))
    } else if(fruit == "mango"){
        c(mango = quo(paste0(tons, collapse=",")))
    }
//common logic
commondf <- df %>% group_by(fruit) %>% summarise(final_result = fruit_info)
```

Comment: FYI, you should have gotten an error when creating `fruit_info` since that is not valid `R` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more straight forward to use the tools available in `dplyr` and `tidyverse` rather than try to create symbols. You could accomplish this like so:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = fruit,
                     names_from = country,
                     values_from = tons) %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(final_result = case_when(
    fruit == "mango" ~ paste0(na.omit(c_across(usa:canada)), "(month)", collapse = ","),
    fruit == "apple" ~ paste0(na.omit(c_across(usa:canada)), collapse = ",")
  )) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

If you know `fruit` only ever has two options then you can simplify this and use `ifelse`. I used `case_when` to allow for additional options, assuming this was a small reproducible example.

**Output**

```
  fruit   usa   ind spain china canada final_result                              
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int> <chr>                                     
1 mango   100   120    60    NA    150 100(month),120(month),60(month),150(month)
2 apple    50    70    NA    90     NA 50,70,90
```

From what I can tell from your code this is your expected output (you may want to drop `usa:canada`).